# Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The storage backend of the staticfiles finder doesn't have a valid location

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, render, django-staticfiles

I was using Django and the static files cannot load, the error is:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: The storage backend of the staticfiles finder <class 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder'> doesn't have a valid location.
```

Here is the views.py:

```
def results(request):
    metaUrl = ""
    if not request.method == 'POST':
        print "Not Post!"
    else:
        metaUrl = request.POST['urls']
    cmodel = InfoController()
    (firstList, wordList, sizeList) = cmodel.controller(metaUrl)
    print "I am at result"
    return render( request, 'infoRetriever/results.html', { 'firstList': firstList, 'wordList': wordList, 'sizeList': sizeList})
```

It's weird that when I was using

```
return render_to_response('infoRetriever/results.html', { 'firstList': firstList, 'wordList': wordList, 'sizeList': sizeList}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

to replace the last sentence in the views.py, the static files loads OK, but other problems would occur. Could anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `DefaultStorageFinder`? If not just get rid of that in `STATICFILES_FINDERS` in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You need put the `MEDIA_ROOT` in your `settings.py`.